# Jobs section in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: support, android-app, jobs

I can't see the section of Jobs in the Stack Exchange app. Do they exist in the app or is it focussed only on the web application?

Answer (score 2):

It's only on the website, and essentially is a separate "product".

Plausibly, had the Stack Overflow app worked out, they might have considered rolling it in, but as is, it's not part of the Stack Exchange app on Android. The app is *only* Q&A.